# How to connect php to ms sql 2017

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using php 5.6.28 and Ms sql express server 2017.

I add the following code.

```
$cid = odbc_connect("DESKTOP-9LIFSBQ\SQLEXPRESS","testdb","");

if (!$cid){
    exit("<strong>Error.</strong>");
}
```

I got the following errors .

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in
```